# Nextjs middleware to tackle matcher

Tags: next.js

I am running a middleware in my NextJS for blog with below matcher
 `matcher: ["/blog/:path*", "/_tenants/:path*"],`

My articles page has the route `/blog/slug-uuid`

I have list page of all blogs /blog

I dont't middle ware function to hit when the list page /blog is run

I tired this solution
 `if (path.endsWith("/blog")) { return; }`

this is working, but function being invoked. I don't want that to happen

Answer (score 0):

According their documentation [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/middleware#matcher) it's stated:

> Note: For backward compatibility, Next.js always considers `/public`
> as `/public/index`. Therefore, a matcher of `/public/:path` will
> match.

I suspect you hit exactly that case and you should use (as you already suggested):

`if (path.endsWith("/blog")) { return; }`

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution to this it was in documentation itself. Instead of at asterisk mark "*" add a "+" ["/blog/:path*", "/_tenants/:path*"] to ["/blog/:path*", "/_tenants/:path+"]